Native android service is not called in Flutter app
I have created a native android service using Kotlin that should be able to be called from another app, the save code is working with a native android app, but with Flutter for android the service is not even been called.
Anyone know what is the issue here? is there others steps for Flutter than
(1) creating service class -> (2) adding service to AndroidManifest)
Thanks

Do you use Method Channel? https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels#architecture

@DoanThai No, because there is no need for it, I just want the service to be called and run the native Kotlin code in it.

To my knowledge, Flutter must use channel to communicate with native code (Kotlin or Java).
